# Rewrite/redirect aspx with specific quesry string to specific wordpress page

Tags: asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've searched through and can't find a working solution...

I've ported a site from asp.net to php. As instructed, I left the internal links as .aspx for seo. For static pages outside wordpress, with no query string, I can work it fine:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^testimonials.aspx$ /testimonials.php [NC,R=301]
```

But, I have some links which include query strings... These links now have to point to pages that are currently inside a wordpress installation. How can I get

```
myawesomesite.com/catalog.aspx?n=My%incredible%20product
```

to redirect to

```
myawesomesite.com/catalog/my-new-incredible-product/
```

AND

```
myawesomesite.com/catalog.aspx?n=My%other%20product
```

to redirect to

```
myawesomesite.com/catalog/my-new-other-product/
```

etc... (in the destination, 'catalog' is the directory that wordpress is installed in)

I've tried all kinds of things but am no expert. I know I need to do something to get apache to catch the query strings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give this a go the below should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^n=My(?:[\ +]|%20)incredible(?:[\ +]|%20)product$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^catalog\.aspx$ http://www.myawesomesite.com/catalog/my-new-incredible-product/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Just amend the parts to match your other URL

I have always found this tool to be useful for redirects

http://seo-website-designer.com/HtAccess-301-Redirect-Generator

Comment: You. Are. A. Bloody. Genius! Thanks so much.